# How to reslove files outside of nestJS project folder

Tags: typescript, nestjs, multer

I am creating a project using nestjs and reactjs. when i am trying to reslove files that outside of nestjs project folder(inside of reactjs project folder), nestjs can not reslove files. it said

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '../../../frontend/src/images/' at mkdirSync

This is my code that trying to reslove files that outside of nestjs folder

```js
// backend/src/uploads/multer-options.ts
import { BadRequestException, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { existsSync, mkdirSync, readdirSync } from 'fs';
import { diskStorage } from 'multer';
import { RESTAURANT_NAME_KEY } from './upload.middleware';

const mainPath = '../../../frontend/src/images/';
const uploadPath = `${mainPath}coverImg/`;

export const multerOptions = {
  fileFilter: (_, file, callback) => {
    if (file.mimetype.match(/\/(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(
        new BadRequestException(
          'Only files with jpg, jpeg, png extension are allowed',
        ),
        false,
      );
    }
  },

  storage: diskStorage({
    destination: (request, file, callback) => {
      if (!existsSync(mainPath)) {
        mkdirSync(mainPath);
      }
      if (!existsSync(uploadPath)) {
        mkdirSync(uploadPath);
      }
      callback(null, uploadPath);
    },
    filename: (request, file, callback) => {
      callback(null,'filename-example');
    },
  }),
};
```

And directory of my project is...

```
project
  ㄴ frontend
    ㄴ src
      ㄴ images
        ㄴ {files that i trying to get}
  ㄴ backend
    ㄴ src
      ㄴ upload (module)
        ㄴ multer-options.ts (config of multer that save files || topside code is multer-options.ts)
        ㄴ uploadPath.controller.ts (controller of save files)
```

Comment: Did you try this?
Maybe whis solution works for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66216160/12111427

Comment: @avnigenc I'm sorry I'm late. And thank you! you saved my day